# How efficient is nginx prefix-based location handling implementation?

Tags: c, nginx, nginx-location, trie, prefix-tree

How is the prefix string location handling implemented within nginx?

- http://nginx.org/r/location

Specifically, it's widely reported that the http://nginx.org/r/server_name matching is done through a hash table — http://nginx.org/docs/http/server_names.html — but there isn't a similar level of detail on the implementation of the `location` directive.

Answer (score 1):

The prefix-based `location` tree is defined to have 3 child node elements at each node:

http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.h#ngx_http_location_tree_node_s

```
462struct ngx_http_location_tree_node_s {
463    ngx_http_location_tree_node_t   *left;
464    ngx_http_location_tree_node_t   *right;
465    ngx_http_location_tree_node_t   *tree;
```

This would appear to be a sort of a data-structure known as a ***prefix tree***, or a ***trie***:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

To find the longest-matching `location` prefix string, in the presence of exact shorter-matching ones, nginx descends further into what it calls the *inclusive* match, into the `tree` child element, keeping in mind the parts of the URI string that have already been matched; otherwise, the structure acts as a regular BST, where, depending on the result of the comparison operation of the URL against the current name of the node (performed by the likes of [memcmp(3)](http://mdoc.su/o/memcmp.3)), nginx descends either into the left or the right node of the sorted tree:

http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.c#ngx_http_core_find_static_location

```
1626    len = r->uri.len;
…
1631    for ( ;; ) {
…
1642        rc = ngx_filename_cmp(uri, node->name, n);
1643
1644        if (rc != 0) {
1645            node = (rc < 0) ? node->left : node->right;
1646
1647            continue;
1648        }
1649
1650        if (len > (size_t) node->len) {
1651
1652            if (node->inclusive) {
1653
1654                r->loc_conf = node->inclusive->loc_conf;
1655                rv = NGX_AGAIN;
1656
1657                node = node->tree;
1658                uri += n;
1659                len -= n;
1660
1661                continue;
1662            }
```

An exact match (`location =`) results in somewhat of a special case of going into the `right` tree, without a prefix optimisation:

```
1663
1664            /* exact only */
1665
1666            node = node->right;
1667
1668            continue;
1669        }
```

The tree is assembled by initially storing all location nodes in a queue, sorting the queue through insertion sort, and then assembling the prefix tree from the middle of the sorted queue:

http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http.c#ngx_http_block

```
277    /* create location trees */
…
283        if (ngx_http_init_locations(cf, cscfp[s], clcf) != NGX_OK) {
…
287        if (ngx_http_init_static_location_trees(cf, clcf) != NGX_OK) {
```

http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http.c#ngx_http_init_locations

```
689    ngx_queue_sort(locations, ngx_http_cmp_locations);
```

http://ngx.su/src/core/ngx_queue.c#ngx_queue_sort

```
48/* the stable insertion sort */
```

http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http.c#ngx_http_init_static_location_trees

```
835    pclcf->static_locations = ngx_http_create_locations_tree(cf, locations, 0);
```

http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http.c#ngx_http_create_locations_tree

```
1075    q = ngx_queue_middle(locations);
…
```

Comment: todo: figure out what does the "inclusive" thing mean — is it merely for nested locations (meaning that the whole thing is a BST in most cases), or does it actually optimise the search based on common prefix of sibling locations?